# Meaning of (const (+1)) in this haskell expression?

Tags: haskell, stack, constants

So, to find out the size of a given stack, I'm using the following function:

```
sizeStack :: S.Stack a -> Int
sizeStack = foldrStack (const (+1)) 0
```

where 'foldrStack' is:

```
foldrStack :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> S.Stack a -> b
foldrStack f z s
  | S.isEmpty s = z
  | otherwise = S.top s `f` foldrStack f z (S.pop s)
```

My question is: what exactly is the role of "const" in sizeStack?

Also, to apply a function to all elements within a stack, I'm using this. Do you have better alternatives?

```
mapStack :: (a -> b) -> S.Stack a -> S.Stack b
mapStack f s = foldrStack (S.push . f) S.empty s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps visualizing it as follows:

```
f = const (+1)
-- eta expand
f x = const (+1) x
-- definition of const:   const a b = a
f x = (+1)
-- eta expand
f x y = (+1) y
-- operator section
f x y = y+1
```

Hence your code is equivalent to

```
sizeStack = foldrStack (\ x y -> y+1) 0
```

which, as Don Stewart explained, means discard the element `x` and increment the counter `y`.

Answer (score 3):

`const` ignores its argument.

So in sizeStack it takes each element of the stack, and adds 1 to the accumulator.
It doesn't need to look at the value on the stack to count it. It is enough to know there is simply an element. So `const` is appropriate.